# jQuery - Round to 2 decimal places and calculate with that number

Tags: jquery, rounding

How to round the tax and brutto values to 2 decimal places...

I have tried to use .toFixed(2) but that returns a string and then i can't calculate with it anymore.

If someone could update the fiddle and make it work please?

And try to input number 23

[DEMO Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5tsgy9/9/)

```
// calculate brutto and tax
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function () {

  var netto = $("#netto").val();
  $("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19).toFixed(2);
  var brutto = $("#brutto").val();
  $("#tax").val(brutto - netto);

});
```

Comment: ``Math.round(netto * 1.19);`` ? https://jsfiddle.net/ze5tsgy9/10/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad this rounds it to integer...i need decimal also

Comment: @lewis4u Please check my answer again, edited now. Hope it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Few issues in your code:

1) You don't need event delegation unless you have elements being loaded dynamically.

2) you should always parse values before doing any mathematical operations on them.

3) you are using `.toFixed(2)` on jquery method which is throwing the error. `toFixed` should be used with float values instead. also make sure that toFixed is used while setting both textbox values:

```
// calculate brutto and tax
$('#netto').on('keyup paste', function () {
  var netto = parseFloat($("#netto").val());
  $("#brutto").val((netto * 1.19).toFixed(2));
  var brutto =  parseFloat($("#brutto").val());
  $("#tax").val((brutto - netto).toFixed(2));
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u9qws2kt/)**

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use Number as the first argument inside `.val()` just to be sure all your values are numbers, otherwise if at least one is not a number, you'll have a problem as I had before. See below:

```
$("#tax").val(Number(brutto - netto).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this may be it helps you,

```
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function () {

   var netto = parseFloat($("#netto").val()).toFixed(2);
   $("#brutto").val((netto * 1.19).toFixed(2));
   var brutto = parseFloat($("#brutto").val()).toFixed(2);
   $("#tax").val((brutto - netto).toFixed(2));

 });
```

Comment: both tax and brutto needs to be rounded to 2 decimal places

Comment: Please check now, modified for you. :) , Issue was you were not using toFixed function on right place.

Comment: thank you but @Milind Anatwar was first who gave the right answer.

Comment: @ManojLodhi: you should always put description about the code added as answer :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Thank you. Will remember. New here and will learn from senior guys like you.. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a jQuery context, you can make good use of the following function :

```
function round(value, precision) {
    var aPrecision = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round(value*aPrecision)/aPrecision;
}
```

Here's your updated fiddle demonstrating its use : https://jsfiddle.net/yuq6kLn2/